# What is the latest stable mongoose version for MongoDB 3.2.8 & MongoDB NodeJS driver 2.1.0?

Tags: mongoose

We are upgrading mongoDB & mongoDB NodeJS driver. Will like to know which version of Mongoose driver I should use? This will be upgraded in production system, so will like stable version.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full support for MongoDB **v3.2** and NodeJS driver **v2.1.0** was introduced in Mongoose **v4.3.0** released in 2015-12-09. That version should be ok for sure.